How to hide watchOS scroll indicator when using .digitalCrownRotation
I'm working on a view for "Text Input" that users can increment via scrolling digital crown, simple code atm like this
Text(label)
  .focusable()
  .digitalCrownRotation(
    detent: $scroll,
    from: -2000,
    through: 2000,
    by: 2,
    sensitivity: .low,
    isContinuous: false,
    isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true
  )

There is other stuff happening like onChange listeners for $scroll State etc. but what's important is that I am testing this within a view that has no over scroll / doesn't use any list or scroll containers, yet I still see os level scroll indicator.
I tried hiding it via .scrollDisabled(true) and .scrollIndicators(.never) on my Text view, but had no luck. Indicators still appear, but are kind of "flickering" in and out. This could be a bug in ios 11, but just in case I wanted to ask this question to see if there are any other sollutions.
